# Vue.js 2 autoescape HTML

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vuejs2, markdown, laravel-5.5

I'm using Vue 2 js with Laravel 5.5.

I have a component data - markdown text.
And I have an vue instance

```
new Vue({
        el : '#lesson_edit',
        data :  {
            lesson : {
                body : `{{ $lesson->body }}`
           }
        }
    });
```

Body string has a '>' symbol. But after assign ot escapes to < .

The problem is the next,I have a vue component, which cconverts markdown to html

```
    <template>
        <div v-html="parsedBody"></div>
    </template>


<script>

    export default {
        props : ['body'],
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        computed : {
            parsedBody(){
                return marked(this.body, { sanitize: true })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

After assigning body and unescpe, I don't get a valid markdown conversion.

WHat should I do?

Add somethin to component?
Refuse this chars escaping in Vue instance? 
Or somethin else... Pleas, help.

Comment: is the conversion from '>' to '<' occurring before it's assigned to vue or after? Also, have you tried {!! !!} instead of {{ }} to display a raw string and not an escaped string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is blade engine on server side which escapes html,  not Vue. You will have to use `{!! $lesson->body !!}` instead of `{{ $lesson->body }}`.

Comment: yeap. it helps.